# svg rotate path around a point

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I have a svg with couple of paths: 
https://jsfiddle.net/homa/sbvsjxqe/

I want to rotate the paths around center. When I add the following code, the path goes outside of view and rotate around a very large circle:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                  attributeType="XML" 
                  type="rotate"
                  from="0 50 50"
                  to="360 50 50" 
                  dur="7s"
                  repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

How can I force the path to rotate around center?

Comment: change the 50 50 numbers in the from and to so that they reflect the path centre instead

Answer (score 1):

The second and third numbers in the `from` and `to` attributes are the coordinates of the centre of rotation.

Set them to the point you want to rotate around. It is probably not (50,50).